# jquery change not fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

I've a problem with jquery change!
This is my .php page

```
 <input id="numero_preventivi" style="display: none;" value="<?php echo $numeriPreventivi['preventivi']; ?>"/>
<input id="numero_preventivi_new" style="display: none;" value="0"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function (){
    var num_pr = $("#numero_preventivi").val();
    var preventivi = new flipCounter('preventivi', {value: num_pr, inc:0, pace:600, auto:false});

    $("#numero_preventivi_new").change(function (){
        var num_pr_new = $("#numero_preventivi_new").val();
        preventivi.incrementTo(num_pr_new);
        });

});
```

And this is my .js function

```
$('#numero_preventivi_new').val(text[0]).change();
```

When my function, in .js page, change value of my hidden div I would fire .change(), but I can't run the function into jquery code. Where is the problem?

Comment: What does `flipCounter()` do? You've set the input's display to `hidden`, so any _user_ interaction won't fire it. Are you trying to trigger the `.change()` event when the `flipCounter()` is created, whatever that may be?

Comment: 'flipCounter()' create a counter. I would change this value to according it with my DB

Comment: It seems that **`text[0]` is not defined**. If it's not the case, post more relevant code, or a JSBin.

Comment: no text[0] is correct! I can't fire change event!

Comment: What version of JQuery are you running?

Comment: Any errors showing up in your console?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the attribute doesn't change the value. Try this:

```
$('#numero_preventivi_new').val(text[0]).change();
```

Working demo: http://jsbin.com/acojed

Comment: Does `text[0]` have a value?? I don't see where it's being defined. That could be your problem.